# How to highlight a path using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Say I have an arrow leading pointing from one node to another node under TikZ. Is there a way to highlight this arrow?

I'm looking for a result that looks (more or less) as though I've printed a diagram and used a highlighter marker to accentuation an arrow. Preferably, only the arrow would be highlighted.

Comment: Could you provide the code showing the diagram you developed? This would help a lot people that want to answer you. `:)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can put a double line(or a thick line) behind your path

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick,-latex, %Regular stuff
preaction={%But before that
draw,yellow,-,% Draw yellow without any arrow head
double=yellow,
double distance=2\pgflinewidth,
}] (0,0) to[bend right] (2cm,2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!