# Tikz Graph How to drop shadow like in figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, shadows

I'm able to generate a tikz node with shadow (lower right) on the node, but this is different than shading not the entire node, but just the circle and edges like in the picture below.

[image]

The shadow on each edge is not really the problem, but the shadow
in the nodes, that is dropped by the circle not only externally
but also inside the node is something that I was not able to do in Tikz.

Minimum working tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[main/.style = {draw, circle, text=black, 
                                   fill=white, circular drop shadow={opacity=0.25}}] 
\node[main] (1) {$x_1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't want the shadow inside fill the node with bg-color, probably white.

Comment: @Harald Lichtenstein: He does want the shadow inside.

Answer (score 8):

There are probably better ways to do this, but here I use a `fuzzy ring 15 percent` fading:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
main/.style = {draw, circle, text=black,  
preaction={draw, ultra thick, transform canvas={yshift=-0.2ex}, path fading=fuzzy ring 15 percent, opacity=0.25}
}] 
\node[main] (1) {$x_1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Node with fuzzy ring shadow]

---

**Edit:**

The solution only works for circles and ellipses - not for e.g. polygons as shown here:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {fadings, shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
main/.style = {draw, regular polygon, text=black,  
preaction={draw, ultra thick, transform canvas={yshift=-0.2ex}, path fading=fuzzy ring 15 percent, opacity=0.25}
}] 
\node[main] (1) {$x_1$}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Pentagon with bad shadow]

To make a more general solution, one could implement a shifted version of *glow* as shown in this answer(by me):
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569645/8650

Comment: Thanks, this is quite similar to what I was looking for. Now I'll try and play with this solution.